# Segmentation fault with singly linked lists

Tags: c, list, crash, malloc

Okay, so I have this school project and I have a pretty big problem. I have spent like 3-4 hours of debugging and I can't find out why it happens.

The program does this: It reads from file "input.in" the following: N(<500), then N files names, the M(<500) and then M "queries".
A query is a line like this: "John & Papa | Dan" and it will return the file indexes where there are either "John and Papa" OR "Dan" included.

The algorithm works, I think, the problem is at saving the hash table.  On small test, the program works fine, then I have a 110 files test and it just "Segmentation faults".

What I know so far before it segmentation faults:

- It faults at 9th file
- It faults at a word that doesn't exists yet in the hash table
- It faults after it passes all the list in searching for a match (at the end of the list, just before adding a new value)

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/fd4c1f6w

Also, the header: http://pastebin.com/H0m7WjrG

Here is the debug information: http://pastebin.com/gvvyjePZ

Input file: http://www.sendspace.com/file/48etji

Please, I really need to solve this and I'm really disappointed.

Comment: I guess nobody will read this much code and go through it. Have you used a debugger to check out what might be wrong?

Comment: I'd _probably_ be inclined to take a look in a couple of hours when my tv show finishes, IF (and only if) you were to also post a copy of the input file. Currently, I'm dissuaded by this point alone. Also, and a separate matter - your function "int is_letter(char c)" may be replaced by the "int isalpha(int c)" function from <ctype.h>

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I added the input files. Somebody told me "The problem is that in Map_t *Alocare_Mapare() as well as in void Realocare_Mapare(Map_t *map, int l) the new entries of map->buckets are not set to NULL and therefore may contain some random bit patterns which are later on interpreted as pointers and dereferenced." So I've changed this: http://pastebin.com/EkCK0GvC BUT I still get the Segmentation fault.

Comment: See updated answer (apologies if you already get notifications of an update)

Answer (score 2):

My comment was going to be a tad long, so I'll post it here. Back before graphical debuggers were so easy to come by, we used a technique known as 'tombstone debugging'. Basically, you just sprinkle some printf statements through the code to determine which is the last place that program execution reached.
`printf("(%d) %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);` is quite useful for this, btw.

I did that with your code as a quick way of isolating the code that needs to be looked at more closely. I found that only the first file, 'date.in' was being read. I then worked out that the second call to put_doc was not returning.

Then I realized you'd posted updated code for Alocare_Mapare and Realocare_Mapare.
:face-palm:

When I updated the code with your new functions, the code proceeded to read all of the input files. I then found that it was crashing in the "`for(i=0;i<nrTokeni;i++)`" loop.

I'll have a better look in a bit, I really like the tv just now! :P

***EDIT:***

Well then, that was some fun I must say. :)
I'll use the code for a future program that searches a list of files for some text.
My tv ended at midnight, and I found your ode hard to read, so based on the description of the requirements you gave, I decided to re-implement it. I did away with the map and hash functions, finding them to be unnecesary for what I understood the ultimate task to be. It's likely (actually hopeful) that the code is somewhat unsuitable for the question as posed - it's more an example of a different approach and *hopefully* an example of code with variables that are more meaningfully named.

I found that the variable names really got in the way of a clear understanding. It also seemed a bit more complicated than need be. If you've got any questions, I'd be happy to answer them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node_t
{
    char *data;
    node_t *next;
};

node_t *makeNewNode(char *newData)
{
    node_t *tmp;
    tmp = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    tmp->data = strdup(newData);
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}

void addNode(node_t **listHead, char *newData)
{
    node_t *theNewNode = makeNewNode(newData);

    if (*listHead == NULL)
        *listHead = theNewNode;

    else
    {
        node_t *curNode = *listHead;
        while (curNode->next != NULL)
            curNode = curNode->next;
        curNode->next = theNewNode;
    }
}

void printList(node_t *nodeList)
{
    node_t *curNode = nodeList;
    while (curNode != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", curNode->data);
        curNode = curNode->next;
    }
}

void readMainInputFile(char *filename, node_t **filesToProcessOut, node_t **searchTermsOut)
{
    int numFiles, numSearchTerms;
    int curFileNum, curSearchTerm;
    const int maxLineLength = 1024;
    char lineBuffer[maxLineLength+1], *endlStrippedFileName, *endlStrippedSearchTerms;

    FILE *fileHandle = fopen(filename, "rt");

    fscanf(fileHandle, "%d\n", &numFiles);
    for (curFileNum=0; curFileNum<numFiles; curFileNum++)
    {
        fgets(lineBuffer, maxLineLength, fileHandle);
        endlStrippedFileName = strtok(lineBuffer, "\r\n");
        addNode(filesToProcessOut, endlStrippedFileName);
    }

    fscanf(fileHandle, "%d\n", &numSearchTerms);
    for (curSearchTerm=0; curSearchTerm<numSearchTerms; curSearchTerm++)
    {
        fgets(lineBuffer, maxLineLength, fileHandle);
        endlStrippedSearchTerms = strtok(lineBuffer, "\r\n");
        addNode(searchTermsOut, endlStrippedSearchTerms);
    }
    fclose(fileHandle);
    printf("Read %d files, %d search terms\n", numFiles, numSearchTerms);
}

int fileLen(FILE *fp)
{
    int result, curPos;
    curPos = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    result = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, curPos, SEEK_SET);
    return result;
}

// searhes a file for any of the strings (seperated by | character) found in a single line from the inupt file.
// this is wasteful - we open load and search the file one time for each of the searchTerms.
// I.e - the InputData below would cause the file to be opened and read 4 times. Ideally, it should only be opened and read once
//  we could fix this by passing a linked list of all of the lines of search terms - I'm too lazy. :-P
//11
//doctor & having
//I & hero | life
//innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet
//shall & turn & out & to & be

bool doesFileContainSearchTerms(char *filename, char *searchTerms)
{
    int fLen;
    bool result;
    char *buffer;
    char *searchTermsCopy = strdup(searchTerms);
    char *curToken, curSearchTerm[100];
    bool spaceAtStart, spaceAtEnd;

    // open file, get length, allocate space for length+1 bytes, zero that memory, read the file
    FILE *fileHandle = fopen(filename, "rt");
    fLen = fileLen(fileHandle);
    buffer = (char*) calloc(1, fLen+1);
    fread(buffer, fLen, 1, fileHandle);
    fclose(fileHandle);

    curToken = strtok(searchTermsCopy, "|");
    while ((curToken != NULL) && (strlen(curToken)!=0))
    {
        memset(curSearchTerm, 0, 100);

        // strip the leading/trailing spaces (and '|' char) from a search term
        // e.g
        //  "I & hero |" --> "I & hero"
        //  " life" --> "life"
        spaceAtStart = spaceAtEnd = false;
        if ((curToken[0] == ' ') || (curToken[0] == '|'))
            spaceAtStart = true;
        if (curToken[strlen(curToken)-1] == ' ')
            spaceAtEnd = true;

        if ((spaceAtStart==false) && (spaceAtEnd==false))
            strcpy(curSearchTerm, curToken);
        else if ((spaceAtStart==false) && (spaceAtEnd==true))
            strncpy(curSearchTerm, curToken, strlen(curToken)-1);
        else if ((spaceAtStart==true) && (spaceAtEnd==false))
            strncpy(curSearchTerm, curToken+1, strlen(curToken)-1);
        else if ((spaceAtStart==true) && (spaceAtEnd==true))
            strncpy(curSearchTerm, curToken+1, strlen(curToken)-2);

   //     printf("CurSearchTerm: ''%s''\n", curSearchTerm);

        // we're searching for _any_ of the text in the search term, e.g "I & hero | life"
        // if we find one of them, then set result to true and stop looking.
        result = false;
        if (strstr(buffer, curSearchTerm) != NULL)
        {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
        // didn't find one of the searchTerms yet, grab the next one
        curToken = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }

    free(buffer);
    free(searchTermsCopy);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    node_t *inputFileList = NULL;
    node_t *searchTermList = NULL;

    readMainInputFile("input.in", &inputFileList, &searchTermList);

    node_t *curFileNameNode = inputFileList;
    while (curFileNameNode != NULL)
    {
        node_t *curSearchTermNode = searchTermList;
        while (curSearchTermNode != NULL)
        {
           // printf("Searching %s for %s\n", curFileNameNode->data, curSearchTermNode->data);
            if (doesFileContainSearchTerms(curFileNameNode->data, curSearchTermNode->data))
                printf("Search hit - file(%s), searchTerm(%s)\n", curFileNameNode->data, curSearchTermNode->data);
            curSearchTermNode = curSearchTermNode->next;
        }
        curFileNameNode = curFileNameNode->next;
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
Read 110 files, 11 search terms
Search hit - file(date.in), searchTerm(I & hero | life)
Search hit - file(date.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date2.in), searchTerm(I & hero | life)
Search hit - file(date2.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date3.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date4.in), searchTerm(I & hero | life)
Search hit - file(date4.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date6.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date6.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date7.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date8.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date9.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date10.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date10.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date11.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date12.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date13.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date14.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date18.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date20.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date20.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date23.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date25.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date25.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date28.in), searchTerm(I & hero | life)
Search hit - file(date29.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date30.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date37.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date38.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date38.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date44.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date45.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date47.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date50.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date52.in), searchTerm(I & hero | life)
Search hit - file(date52.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date53.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date61.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date68.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date75.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date76.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date76.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date77.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date78.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date81.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date84.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date88.in), searchTerm(looking | fire | called & another)
Search hit - file(date89.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date91.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date92.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date100.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date102.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)
Search hit - file(date110.in), searchTerm(innocently | that | know & will & it & I & yet)

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.308 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Wow, he owes you a cookie or something for this.  Wish I could double up-vote you for your work.

Comment: Cheers Mate! I appreciate your comments. As long as it's not browser-based, I'll take it! (the cookie, that is) Since I don't come here for money, nor a pi$$ing contest, it's all about the learning and the teaching. I'm fortunate enough to receive both in spades. Nice to see a fellow asm coder bouncing about. :-) S.

Comment: Thanks you, oh my :) I'll go immediately into fixing it! Huuuge thanks.

Comment: The thing is I'm forced to work with their header (and the hash table and typedefs). I guess the real question I have since I understood where my code crashes how do I correctly allocate that Map_t structure that has a Node_t** member.

Comment: I thought that may well be the case :( - Not sure. I've never used a map or hash table in over 20 years of coding (shhh!), I'm not intimately familiar with their workings. As I said earlier - the naming conventions used for the variables throughout the program make it very hard for me to read. Though, I do notice that in the function "Realocare_Mapare", that after you re-allocate memory, you then proceed to _wipe out all existing data_ in it's buckets. Is this intended, or should that function be ensuring that the newly allocated memory doesn't contain non-NULL values? Won't getDocs fail?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the badly named variables (I'm working on it!). I've sent my code for checking (I head a deadline), so the changes I'll make will only be made to put my mind at peace. I don't want to wipe all the existing data (I'm quite sure I don't do that). The map->buckets[i] (given an i index) should be the last element from the list (that's why I make it NULL), so when I go through the list in "IsWordInList", it's not an infinite loop. 'buckets' is supposed to be an array of lists, so buckets[0] is a list for the words that have the hash 0, buckets[1] for those with a hash of 1.

Comment: Also, funnily enough, when I first read the task, I proceeded to make the same thing a code that does almost the same thing but doesn't respect the header (~about 250 lines of code), though I have not used lists, but rather some arrays. Sorry for answering so hard, I'm new here and I don't have any kind of notifications (as you pointed in your first post, I'm looking into that). I've always wanted to make an account here but never had a reason. The fact that you put an effort into helping me is a hard-proof that this site is full of awesome people.

Comment: Aw shucks, you're too kind. Alas, I just can't provide any more direction for you in this question. It took me about 2 hours to code it from scratch while watching tv, yet after several more hours trying to debug it and work out what on earth is going on, I'm just getting frustrated and a sore head. Good luck. (Oh, I didn't think there would be a notification when I edited my answer, but just wanted to be safe :) ) StackOverflow is certainly my forum of choice, both questions and answers are generally quite intelligent. Much better than "It's urgentzz! Plz send me the codezz!!!!" forums. :-)